# Functions with alert boxes from an outside JQuery file don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML excerpt:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="alert_box.js">
</script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <input type="button" id="name" value="click" >

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what's in my alert_box.js

```
$('#name').click(function(){
 alert('alert box working');
});
```

Both JQuery and alert_box.js are imported

Comment: you need to add the script in a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: What do you want in this situation?

Comment: I did add the DOM ready handler and it still doesn't work. I moved the .js import all around the body and head and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers given, this should be solved. But I will summarize it. You may also want to just use a remote jquery script hosted somewhere else, which you can reference like so:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise...

```
<html>
  <head>
      //make sure your path here is correct
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      //make sure your path here is correct
      <script type="text/javascript" src="alert_box.js"></script>
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" id="name" value="click" >
  </body>
</html>
```

alert_box.js

```
(function() {
    $('#name').click(function() {
        alert('alert box working');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tested my jq for presence and it was loaded, however still wasn't working. It could've been corrupt. Your link resolved the problem however, thanks. I am voting you. Still a problem however. Check out my next post, please.

Answer (score 0):

When you call that, the DOM isn't yet ready therefore, there is no `#name` element which you're looking for. Wrap your code in DOM ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').click(function() {
        alert('alert box working');
    });
});
```

Or bring the `<script src="alert_box.js">` before `</body>`

[Learn about DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Now, after EternalHour provided me with an external JQuery source, some of the functionality resumed to normal. However, this would not work and I have no idea why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title> 


      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="alert_box.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      if(window.jQuery){           <!--this is a small test I ran ti see if jquery is loaded/-->
        alert('jquery functional');
      }else{
        alert('jquery not loaded');
      }

      </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <input type="button" value="submit">


  </body>
</html>
```

Now back to alert_box.js ...

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  $(':button').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('value','loading...');     
    });
  });
```

The button won't change value, what's causing this?